# GROUP BY Clause - Not working in HSQLDB for Blackberry 7.0

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have used HSQL query with Group By Clause in my application for Blackberry 7.0.

I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT Cus.cus_id,Cus.cus_last_name,Inv.inv_id,Sum(Inv.inv_due_amt) as ACCOUNT
FROM Customer as Cus,Invoice as Inv
Where Cus.cus_id=Inv.cus_id 
GROUP BY Cus.cus_last_name;
```

I am getting as `"Not in aggregate function or group by clause error"`

How to fix this issue?

Comment: If you want the sum of invoice amounts, you cannot get the invoice id because there may be two or more invoices per customer. Remove the last_name and inv_id from query and use GROUP BY cus.cus_id. If inv_id is PRIMARY KEY, then you can add the cus_last_name to the query with HSQLDB 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

The columns Cus.cus_id and Inv.ind_id ned to either be in an aggregate function or in your GROUP BY clause. I suspect you want:

```
SELECT 
  Cus.cus_id,Cus.cus_last_name,Inv.inv_id,Sum(Inv.inv_due_amt) as ACCOUNT 
FROM 
  Customer as Cus,Invoice as Inv 
Where 
  Cus.cus_id=Inv.cus_id 
GROUP BY 
  Cus.cus_last_name, Cus.cus_id, Inv.inv_id
```

However I'm not sure that will give the grouping you actually desire. This may be more what you want:

```
SELECT 
  Cus.cus_id,Cus.cus_last_name,Sum(Inv.inv_due_amt) as ACCOUNT 
FROM 
  Customer as Cus,Invoice as Inv 
Where 
  Cus.cus_id=Inv.cus_id 
GROUP BY 
  Cus.cus_last_name, Cus.cus_id
```

Comment: Thanks for replying my post. I have tried with the query but I am not getting the actual results what I need.

Comment: You should provide examples of your data set and the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

All non-aggregate columns should be part og GROUP BY Clause. Try this

```
SELECT Cus.cus_id,Cus.cus_last_name,Inv.inv_id,Sum(Inv.inv_due_amt) as ACCOUNT
FROM Customer as Cus,Invoice as Inv
Where Cus.cus_id=Inv.cus_id 
GROUP BY Cus.cus_id,Cus.cus_last_name,Inv.inv_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried by adding all the non-aggregate fields in Group By clause but I am getting 242 records.  I have to get only 48 records if I use only Cus.cus_last_name in group by clause